# Mutiliple Annotations in Skobbler(skmaps) map , how to show multiple markers in skobbler maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am able to implement `SKAnnotation` to set a single annotation in `skmaps`
Now i just want to add multiple annotations in `skmaps` map android
So here is the code snippet .. Any help will be appreciated ....

```
SKAnnotation annotation1 = new SKAnnotation(10);
// set annotation location
annotation1.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.4200, 37.7765));
// set minimum zoom level at which the annotation should be visible
annotation1.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
// set the annotation's type
annotation1.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_RED);
// render annotation on map
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
```

I have looked everywhere and didn't get anything useful on how to implement this .....

Answer (score 5):

Make an array that contains multiple coordinate data. Use a for loop to create an annotation for every single object in your array. Like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<coordinatesArray.count;i++) {
SKAnnotation annotation1 = new SKAnnotation(10);
// set annotation location
annotation1.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(latitude, longitude));
// set minimum zoom level at which the annotation should be visible
annotation1.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
// set the annotation's type
annotation1.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_RED);
// render annotation on map
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
}
```

get the latitude and longitude from your coordinatesArray object i